# Jcrop in Meteor: Can't stop dragging (if bootstrap package is added)

Tags: meteor, jcrop

I want to allow the user to crop and image using Jcrop.  I've installed the jquery-jcrop smart package, and patched it to include the css and gif files (see my pull request on that project).

Now things look good, but once the user clicks/drags on the image, he can never let go.  From the first drag (or even a click), he is able to adjust the size of selection, but releasing the mouse button does nothing, and every mouse movement continues to change the selection size.

To reproduce:

```
1. mrt create tmp

2. mrt add jquery-jcrop

3. in tmp.html <body>:
       <img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/sOrqCDfqSbqkkHbbu1pC"
            id="target" />  

4. in tmp.js isClient:
        Meteor.startup(function() {
            $('#target').Jcrop();
        });
```

Running mrt now and accessing the page will show the desired behaviour (might look weird though without the patch from the pull request mentioned above).

Stopping, running "mrt add bootstrap", rerunning will show the problem as described above.

I should note that a non-Meteor project, with jquery, jquery-jcrop and bootstrap works without problems.

Comment: given this is most likely a fault in your code... can we see the code?

Comment: sure.  i tracked the problem down to bootstrap but not sure where yet.  see edits above.

Comment: ok I tracked the problem down to the bootstrap.js in Bootstrap 2.3.0.  Replacing with Bootstrap 2.3.1 fixes the problem.  I reviewed the Bootstrap Changelog and don't really see the relevant change, but this works :)

Answer (score 0):

ok I tracked the problem down to the bootstrap.js in Bootstrap 2.3.0. Replacing with Bootstrap 2.3.1 fixes the problem. I reviewed the Bootstrap Changelog and don't really see the relevant change, but this works :)